# Valgrind Memory Leaks, Invalid free()

Tags: c, memory-leaks, valgrind

```
typedef struct {
   int **a;
   int **b;
   int **c;
   int i;
} test_t;

test_t *create(int i) {
    test_t *test = malloc(i * sizeof(test_t));

    test->i = i;

    test->c = malloc(i * sizeof(int *));
    for (int j = 0; j < i; ++j) {
        test->c[j] = malloc(sizeof(int *));
    }

    test->a = malloc(sizeof(int *));
    test->a = &(test->c[0]);
    test->b = malloc(sizeof(int *));
    test->b = &(test->c[0]);
    return test;
}

void delete(test_t *test) {
    free(test->a);
    free(test->b);
    for (int i = 0; i < test->i; ++i)
        free(test->c[i]);
    free(test->c);
    free(test);
}

int main() {
    test_t *test;

    test = create(3);

    delete(test);

    return 0;
}
```

What's wrong with this code?

When I run Valgrind, I get 5 errors and some memory leaks.

I don't see any memory leak, do you?

I get errors like:

```
Invalid free() / delete / delete[] / realloc()
Address 0x4a380e0 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 24 free'd
Block was alloc'd at
Invalid read of size 8
```

Could anybody help me with that, please?

*P.S. The code works fine, but it has memory leaks, so it doesn't.*

Comment: @dxiv Sorry, typo. Look at that now.

Comment: @JohnDoe copy/paste only the code that you tested.

Comment: 'test->a' gets malloced, but then overwritten in the next line.  Same with test->b.

Comment: `test->a = malloc(sizeof(int *)); test->a = &(test->c[0]);` What do you think that does? The second expression overwrites the `malloc` result from the first. That results in a memory leak. And when you free `test->a` it will be somewhere inside `c`. Which is exactly what valgrind tells you.

Comment: @kaylum Hmmm. So, `test->a = some-address` overwrites `test->a` address? When I try to `printf` that, it is not overwritten. That's weird. I'd like to store an address of a first item in array to `test->a` and `test->b`.

Comment: @MartinJames This is only the code I am testing.

Comment: Of course it overwrites. Same as if you do `a = 10; a = 11;`. The result will be `11` not `10` right?

Comment: *I'd like to store an address of a first item in array*. You certainly can do that if you want to. If you want to point to some existing memory then just point to it but you shouldn't `malloc` new memory first (and then throw it away immediately). And you shouldn't try to `free` the same memory twice which is what you do if you free it from two different pointers that point to the same thing.

Comment: So, what about `*(test->a) = test->c`?

Comment: You can do that after the `malloc`. But you said: *I'd like to store an address of a first item*. That would be storing an `int` and not an address.

Comment: I don't know, I am lost.

Comment: I thought, I cannot overwrite an address of dynamic allocated variable to not cause memory leaks. And I thought an address of `test->a` is `&(test->a)`, but it seems it is not. I thought that `test->a` is where the pointer points and `*(test->a)` is the value of where the pointers points.

Answer (score 0):

Eyeballing it...

```
    test->a = malloc(sizeof(int *));
    test->a = &(test->c[0]);
    test->b = malloc(sizeof(int *));
    test->b = &(test->c[0]);
```

Since `test->a` and `test->b` are immediately reassigned, the mallocs have no effect except to leak memory. The above should be simply...

```
    test->a = &(test->c[0]);
    test->b = &(test->c[0]);
```

With that the rule of thumb that the number of mallocs should equal the number of frees works. Three mallocs, one in a loop. Three frees, one in a loop.

```
void delete(test_t *test) {
    for (int i = 0; i < test->i; i++) {
        free(test->c[i]);
    }
    free(test->c);
    free(test);
    test->a = NULL;
    test->b = NULL;
}
```

`test->a` and `test->b` should not be freed as they are borrowing `test->c[0]`'s memory. We need too avoid freeing it twice. Since that borrowed memory is invalid and can no longer be used, we set it to `NULL` as a precaution.